# Android runtime error: "FATAL EXCEPTION", instantiating ListFragment and adding to ActionBar

Tags: android-fragments

The complaint appears to be with ListFragment creating a view: 
    public class MedsListActivity extends Activity implements ListSelectionListener{

```
public static ArrayList<Medication> lm;

private final static MedDetailFragment medDetailFragment = new MedDetailFragment();
private final static MedListFragment medListFragment = new MedListFragment();
private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.app.Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
 */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_medlist);
    populateMedlist();
    addTabs();
}

private void addTabs(){
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setTitle("RxShare");
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    Tab tab = actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.action_medlist);
    MedListFragment mlf = new MedListFragment();
    tab.setTabListener(new TabListener(mlf));
    actionBar.addTab(tab);
}
...
}

public class MedListFragment extends ListFragment {

    private final static String LOG_TAG = MedListFragment.class.getCanonicalName();
    private ArrayList<Medication> lm;
    ListSelectionListener mListener = null;
    int mCurrIdx = -1;

    public interface ListSelectionListener {
        public void onListSelection(int index);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(false);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {



        String dataString[] = { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six",
            "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten" };

        ListAdapter myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, dataString);
        setListAdapter(myAdapter);

        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }
```

The parent activity layout xml(R.layout.activity_medlist) is the following:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

This results in the following stacktrace in Eclipse console:

> 08-18 17:17:07.914: E/FragmentManager(2303): **No view found for id 0x7f0a0019 (com.rxshare:id/action_medlist) for fragment MedListFragment**{40cd9158 #0 id=0x7f0a0019} 08-18 17:17:07.914: E/FragmentManager(2303): Activity state: 08-18 17:17:07.924:
>       E/FragmentManager(2303):   Local Activity 40d786c0 State: 08-18 17:17:07.934: E/FragmentManager(2303):     mResumed=false mStopped=false mFinished=false 08-18 17:17:07.934: E/FragmentManager(2303):     mLoadersStarted=false 08-18 17:17:07.944: E/FragmentManager(2303):     mChangingConfigurations=false 08-18 17:17:07.944: E/FragmentManager(2303):     mCurrentConfig={1.0 310mcc260mnc en_US ldltr sw360dp w360dp h567dp 320dpi nrml port finger
>       -keyb/v/h -nav/h s.6} 08-18 17:17:07.954: E/FragmentManager(2303):   Active Fragments in 40d787b0: 08-18 17:17:07.954: E/FragmentManager(2303):     #0: MedListFragment{40cd9158 #0 id=0x7f0a0019} 08-18 17:17:07.964: E/FragmentManager(2303):       mFragmentId=#7f0a0019 mContainerId=#7f0a0019 mTag=null 08-18 17:17:07.964: E/FragmentManager(2303):       mState=0 mIndex=0 mWho=android:fragment:0 mBackStackNesting=0 08-18 17:17:07.964: E/FragmentManager(2303):       mAdded=true mRemoving=false mResumed=false mFromLayout=false mInLayout=false 08-18 17:17:07.974: E/FragmentManager(2303):       mHidden=false mDetached=false mMenuVisible=true mHasMenu=false 08-18 17:17:07.974: E/FragmentManager(2303):       mRetainInstance=true mRetaining=false mUserVisibleHint=true 08-18 17:17:07.974: E/FragmentManager(2303):     mFragmentManager=FragmentManager{40d787b0 in MedsListActivity{40d786c0}} 08-18 17:17:07.974: E/FragmentManager(2303):       mActivity=com.rxshare.MedsListActivity@40d786c0 08-18 17:17:07.984: E/FragmentManager(2303):   Added Fragments: 08-18 17:17:07.984: E/FragmentManager(2303):     #0: MedListFragment{40cd9158 #0 id=0x7f0a0019} 08-18 17:17:07.994: E/FragmentManager(2303):   FragmentManager misc state: 08-18 17:17:07.994: E/FragmentManager(2303):     mActivity=com.rxshare.MedsListActivity@40d786c0 08-18 17:17:07.994: E/FragmentManager(2303):     mContainer=android.app.Activity$1@40d78828 08-18 17:17:08.004: E/FragmentManager(2303):     mCurState=2 mStateSaved=false mDestroyed=false 08-18 17:17:08.004: E/FragmentManager(2303):   View Hierarchy: 08-18 17:17:08.004: E/FragmentManager(2303):     com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{40d792f0 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-0,0} 08-18 17:17:08.014: E/FragmentManager(2303):       android.widget.LinearLayout{40d799b8 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-0,0} 08-18 17:17:08.024: E/FragmentManager(2303):         com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer{40d7a598 V.ED.... ......ID 0,0-0,0 #1020359 android:id/action_bar_container} 08-18 17:17:08.024: E/FragmentManager(2303):           com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView{40d7ab80 V.E..... ......ID 0,0-0,0 #102035a android:id/action_bar} 08-18 17:17:08.024: E/FragmentManager(2303):             android.widget.LinearLayout{40d7bc98 V.....C. ......I. 0,0-0,0} 08-18 17:17:08.034: E/FragmentManager(2303):               com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView$HomeView{40d7cdb8 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-0,0} 08-18 17:17:08.034: E/FragmentManager(2303):         android.widget.ImageView{40d7d218 G.ED.... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #1020246 android:id/up} 08-18 17:17:08.044: E/FragmentManager(2303):            android.widget.ImageView{40d7d598 V.ED.... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #102002c android:id/home} 08-18 17:17:08.054: E/FragmentManager(2303):          com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView{40d807c0 G.E..... ......ID 0,0-0,0 #102035b android:id/action_context_bar} 08-18 17:17:08.054: E/FragmentManager(2303):           com.android.internal.widget.ScrollingTabContainerView{40d82850 VFED.... ......I. 0,0-0,0} 08-18 17:17:08.054: E/FragmentManager(2303):             android.widget.LinearLayout{40d77120 V.ED.... ......I. 0,0-0,0} 08-18 17:17:08.064: E/FragmentManager(2303):               com.android.internal.widget.ScrollingTabContainerView$TabView{40cdf7e0 VFE...C. ..S...I. 0,0-0,0} 08-18 17:17:08.064: E/FragmentManager(2303):                 android.widget.TextView{40cd8db8 V.ED.... ..S...I. 0,0-0,0} 08-18 17:17:08.074: E/FragmentManager(2303):         android.widget.FrameLayout{40d80d38 V.ED.... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #1020002 android:id/content} 08-18 17:17:08.074: E/FragmentManager(2303):       android.widget.FrameLayout{40d81dc8 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #1020011 android:id/tabcontent} 08-18 17:17:08.074: E/FragmentManager(2303):    com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer{40d811b8 G.ED.... ......ID 0,0-0,0 #102035c android:id/split_action_bar} 08-18 17:17:08.104: D/AndroidRuntime(2303): Shutting down VM 08-18 17:17:08.104: W/dalvikvm(2303): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930) 08-18 17:17:08.143: E/AndroidRuntime(2303): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 08-18 17:17:08.143: E/AndroidRuntime(2303): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.rxshare/com.rxshare.MedsListActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0a0019 (com.rxshare:id/action_medlist) for fragment MedListFragment{40cd9158
>       #0 id=0x7f0a0019} 08-18 17:17:08.143: E/AndroidRuntime(2303):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180) 08-18 17:17:08.143: E/AndroidRuntime(2303):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230) 08-18 17:17:08.143: E/AndroidRuntime(2303):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 08-18 17:17:08.143: E/AndroidRuntime(2303):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234) 08-18 17:17:08.143: E/AndroidRuntime(2303):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 08-18 17:17:08.143: E/AndroidRuntime(2303):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 08-18 17:17:08.143: E/AndroidRuntime(2303):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 08-18 17:17:08.143: E/AndroidRuntime(2303):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 08-18 17:17:08.143: E/AndroidRuntime(2303):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 08-18 17:17:08.143: E/AndroidRuntime(2303):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 08-18 17:17:08.143: E/AndroidRuntime(2303):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 08-18 17:17:08.143: E/AndroidRuntime(2303):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 08-18 17:17:08.143: E/AndroidRuntime(2303): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0a0019 (com.rxshare:id/action_medlist) for fragment MedListFragment{40cd9158 #0 id=0x7f0a0019} 08-18 17:17:08.143: E/AndroidRuntime(2303):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:877) 08-18 17:17:08.143: E/AndroidRuntime(2303):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057) 08-18 17:17:08.143: E/AndroidRuntime(2303):   at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682) 08-18 17:17:08.143: E/AndroidRuntime(2303):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435) 08-18 17:17:08.143: E/AndroidRuntime(2303):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5113) 08-18 17:17:08.143: E/AndroidRuntime(2303):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2153) 08-18 17:17:08.143: E/AndroidRuntime(2303):   ... 11 more